# Giving static filenames for build files in vue-cli3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am using vue-cli3, when i build using npm run build -- --mode=production, it gives 2 css files and 2 js files.

Everytime i make a code change the name of the file also changes like app.de90cdf7.js and chunk-vendors.a9204242.js.

Is there a way in vue-cli to hardcode the files names as app.js and chunk-vendors.js ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this? When building the app, the files are automatically loaded dynamically in the final build, so you wouldn't have to worry about naming of the files (they can be arbitrarily named, and in this case, has a content hash appended to the end of it). Hashes are added for the purpose of cache-busting, and you probably will want to rely on that.

Comment: Hi @Terry, thanks for the reply. Yes i do understand the hashing concept. I am including all the .js and .css files into my html application. So every time i change something in code i need to change the names of the files in my HTML files. so i thought if i can export everything in a same number, changing the name will not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm little late to the party. We can chain webpack to apply name changes.
Using version @vue/cli 5.0.4 in year 2022

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack : (config) => {
    config.output.filename('[name].js');
  },
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[name].css'
    }
  }
});
```

[image]